# Alpine.js interop - set variable to TypeScript app

Tags: alpine.js

I would like to have a checkbox that will set a variable to `true` when it is clicked

```html
<input @click="settings.advancedMode = true"> type="checkbox" id="AdvancedMode" >
<label for="AdvancedMode">Advanced Mode</label>
```

In my separate app I initialize a variable like this:

```js
export var settings = {
    advancedMode: false,
}
```

but when I try clicking on the input, I get an error:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined
    at eval (eval at saferEvalNoReturn (big.ts:3400), <anonymous>:3:21)
    at saferEvalNoReturn (big.ts:3400)
    at Component.evaluateCommandExpression (evented.js:172)
    at runListenerHandler (evented.js:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.handler
```

I should probably use x-bind but I don't know the right syntax for checkbox. As a beginner it would be helpful to have [more examples](https://gist.github.com/chapmanjacobd/f51e41b2d4c36b33803be0ca5e2e8e3e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that TypeScript code gets bundled and that bundling process enforces module scoping. This means `settings` isn't available in the global scope/on the global object.

The solution, which is noted in the [docs](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-data) is to do `window.settings = { advancedMode: false };`. You should get a TypeScript warning when you do this, the solution to that is to do:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    settings: any;
  }
}
```

However, this solution won't have `settings` be a "reactive object": when you change values in it, the user interface (using Alpine.js) won't update.

What you probably want to do is the following.

In a JavaScript/TypeScript file:

```js
window.settings = function () {
  return {
    advancedMode: false
  }
}
```

Then in your template (HTML/Alpine.js file):

```html
<div x-data="settings()">
  <input @click="advancedMode = true"> type="checkbox" id="AdvancedMode" >
  <label for="AdvancedMode">Advanced Mode</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I was having some trouble with this solution so I switched to using  https://github.com/ryangjchandler/spruce 

I think my problem was that I needed to run the window.settings code before the alpine.js import statement. This is what Spruce does and it is working